# Swift: Screenshot without Tab Bar

Tags: ios, swift, screenshot, uigraphicscontext

I know it's fairly easy to take a screenshot of the entire screen, with or without the navigation and status bars, using a `UIGraphicsImageContext` but is there a way to take one (or crop one) so that the navigation bar is visible, but the status bar and tab bar are **not** visible?

I've restated this question so it's more clear and added a bounty [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32021204/swift-cropping-a-screenshot).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set `tabbar.hidden = true`

Cropping is easy as well, after taking screenshot:

```
let cropRect = CGRectMake(posX, posY, width, height) // depends how you want to crop it

let imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(yourScreenshot.CGImage, cropRect)
let image: UIImage = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef)!
```